# Simplifying a three-variable expression

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Can this expression be simplified or written in a more compact form:

$$a(1-b)(1-c) + b(1-a)(1-c) + c(1-a)(1-b)$$

Comment: $(a+b+c)-2(ab+bc+ac)+3abc$

Comment: Multiply out, try to collect similar terms (like @Oleg567's comment shows).